# How do you add a AVCaptureVideoPrevieweLayer to a view in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ipad, avfoundation

I have an AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer and i'd like to add it to a UIView (like the @IB thing) from my storyboard. How would I go about doing that?

This is the code for my AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, PreviewDelegate {

    var cameraPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
    @IBOutlet weak var topBorder: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        // Functions for capturing image
        setupCaptureSession()
        setupDevice()
        setupInputOutput()
        setupPreviewLayer()
        startRunningCaptureSession()

        super.viewDidLoad();

    }

    func setupPreviewLayer() {
        cameraPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        cameraPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect
        cameraPreviewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
        cameraPreviewLayer?.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(cameraPreviewLayer!, at: 0)

        cameraPreviewLayer?.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        cameraPreviewLayer?.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: topBorder.frame.height)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below codes :

```
    cameraPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
    cameraPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
    cameraPreviewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
    cameraPreviewLayer?.zPosition = -1
    cameraPreviewLayer?.frame = containerView.layer.bounds

    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(cameraPreviewLayer!, at: 0)
```